# Find the sum of all the numeric values of all the objects in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects like this:

```
 data: [
        a:[
            {keyone:'a', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 23, keyfour: 15},
            {keyone:'a', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 23, keyfour: 15},
            {keyone:'a', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 23, keyfour: 15},
            {keyone:'a', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 23, keyfour: 15}
        ]
    ]
```

I want to first find all the keys which have a numeric value, then add them up and create a new object with the key and the sum as the value for it.

Result should be:

```
sums = { keythree: 92, keyfour: 60 }
```

I am using `Lodash`. This is where I stand right now:

```
//Get all group names
    var keys = Object.keys(data);

    //Do this for all groups
    for(var i = 0; i< keys.length; i++) {
        //For all user records in the group
        _u.forEach(data[keys[i]], function(item) {
            //Find those keys which have a numeric value
            var numKeys = Object.keys(_u.pick(item, _u.isNumber));

            //For each of these keys, calculate the sum
            _u(numKeys).forEach(function(n) {
                _u.set(sums, n+'['+keys[i]+']', _u.sum(_u.map(data[keys[i]], n)));
            }).value();
        });
    }
```

This works, and I get the expected result. But I am trying to reduce the loops and make it more efficient. I think `Lodash` has a way to do it in a better way, but the documentation is pretty hard to go through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var data = {
  a: [
    { keyone:'a', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 23, keyfour: 15 },
    { keyone:'a', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 23, keyfour: 15 },
    { keyone:'a', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 23, keyfour: 15 },
    { keyone:'a', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 23, keyfour: 15 }
  ],
  
  b: [
    { keyone:'b', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 10, keyfour: 100 },
    { keyone:'b', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 10, keyfour: 100 },
    { keyone:'b', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 10, keyfour: 100 },
    { keyone:'b', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 10, keyfour: 100 }
  ]
};

var result = _.mapValues(data, function (e) {
  return _.reduce(e, function (prev, current) {
    return _(current)
      .pick(_.isNumber)
      .mapValues(function (value, key) {
         return (prev[key] || 0) + value;
      })
      .value();
  }, {});
});

console.log( result );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Managed to calculate the grand total.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce):

```
_.reduce(data, function(result, item) {
    return _.merge(result, _.pick(item, _.isFinite), _.add);
}, {});
```

Each iteration uses [merge()](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) to update the reduce accumulator. We can use [pick()](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) + [isFinite()](https://lodash.com/docs#isFinite) so that only number values are merged. The [add()](https://lodash.com/docs#add) function adds the two values for a given key value. This is a customizer function for `merge()`.

Comment: Thanks. This looks really neat. But `item` is an array of objects, and the `_.pick` operation fails to parse it. That is where another loop would be needed.